# Detecting when the browser has requested to download a file

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension, cross-browser

I would like to write an extension (to several browsers - IE, Chrome, FF) that will detect when the browser was asked to download a file. When this happens, I would like to control the download and possibly redirect to another file. 
Any idea how to do this for latest browsers?

The only example I have found (for IE) was [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSIEDownloadManager-8ab5d910) but it is a very old code and not relevant any more for newer browsers (uses BHO which I understand are not supported any more).

I have found this super cool [platform](http://crossrider.com/) http://crossrider.com/ that allows creating extensions to multiple browsers but they do not support these kind of tasks.

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

For chrome extensions ( Microsoft Edge extensions in the future, which doesn't support `downloads` api now), you could take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads, specifically for your requirements:

- Detect downloads starting: [`chrome.downloads.onCreated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onCreated)
- Control the downloads: [`chrome.downloads.pause`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-pause),[`chrome.downloads.resume`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-resume),[`chrome.downloads.cancel`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-cancel)
- Redirect to another file: [`chrome.downloads.download`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download)

Comment: Do you know if this is possible for Internet explorer 10..? Without using BHO?

Comment: @Dafna, sorry I have little experience with plugins for IE :(